# How to automatically connect to a wiFi network and turn off 4g LTE

Tags: wi-fi, data-connection, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I'd like my Samsumg Galaxy S4 verizon phone to be able to connect to my preferred wifi networks (office and home) automatically, while at the same time turn off the 4G LTE data plan.

As of right now, I have it set up such that it'd connect auto to wifi, but when I am connected to wifi I still see the 4g LTE active.  I could deactivate the 4G LTE and activate it later, but I am looking for a way to do this automatically, no user involved.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, mobile data should be turned off automatically by the system when WiFi is connected. If you're sure it's mobile data which is on, you could try some [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) tools to handle this, e.g. [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (Condition: WiFi connected, Task: mobile data off), or [Llama - Location Profiles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) (here I don't know the steps, but it can do that as well).

Comment: nice app, just got it and it solved my problem ;-)

Comment: Great! Which of the two did you decide for? If Llama, maybe you could describe the steps involved with a few words?

Comment: Oh no, I decided to use Tasker.

Comment: Yepp -- just thought so when seeing your new question :) You won't regret those few bucks it costs. On some forums, as soon as somebody starts "How..." it shouts "Tasker, Tasker" from all directions before he can finish his question #D